# Getting value of enum initialized with string in Java

Tags: java, enums

I have enum which is defined and initialized with string as below

```
public enum Code {
    OK( "OK" ),
    ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND ( "FILE_NOT_FOUND xxxxxxxxx" ),
    ERROR_AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE("AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE xxxxxxx" ),
    ERROR_AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE("AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE xxxxxxx" ),
    ERROR_DUPLICATE_DEF("DUPLICATE_DEF xxxxxxx"),
    ERROR("ERROR xxxxxx")

    private final String errorText;

    private Code(String error) {
        errorText = error;
    }
}
```

If I have Enum value, ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND how do I get corresponding string Value  "FILE_NOT_FOUNDxxxxxxxxx"?

Thanks,

Comment: The code that you have posted is not valid Java. It won't compile on its own.

Comment: I should have posted the complete code, I have compiled code with all the initialization function, except for the function which return the string value, which I found out latter.

Answer (score 5):

The code you posted won't compile.  You're looking for this:

```
public enum Code {
  OK( "OK" ),
  ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND ( "FILE_NOT_FOUND xxxxxxxxx" ),
  ERROR_AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE("AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE xxxxxxx" ),
  ERROR_AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE("AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE xxxxxxx" ),
  ERROR_DUPLICATE_DEF("DUPLICATE_DEF xxxxxxx"),
  ERROR("ERROR xxxxxx");

  private final String text;

  private Code(String text) {
    this.text = text;
  }

  public String getText() {
    return this.text;
  }
}
```